# Passing encrypted form values via url parameter to thank you page

Tags: wffm

I'm quite new here so don't go too hard on me if some things might be a bit unclear.

**A little background info:** Last week I implemented so when a form is submitted, we take all the info and encrypt it to a string and then pass it to the end of a link in an email that is set as a `save action` for this form. The link goes to the next part of the form flow, when clicking this, the encrypted string will be decrypted and then used to populate available fields on the second form and so on. Looks something like this:

> *webpage.com/form2?[info]* **is replaced with:** *webpage.com/form2?info=e4x5kd...*

This was quite easy since I could easily add a check to the email token replace methods that are already in place. I am working with WFFM.

What I need to do now is basically the exact same thing, but I want to pass this string to a thank you page of a form. My problem right now is that I do not know how to replace a `token` in a link, on a thank you page.

The flow should look something like:

**Form 1 =>** (pass encrypted string somehow) **=> Thank you page =>** (click link to Form 2 and continue to pass along encrypted string) **=> Form 2** (decrypt string and populate)

Not sure if I can go with the email style implementation or if I need to go with another type, all I want is to pass this string from one form to another via a thank you page.

As mentioned, I'm still kind of new to sitecore so any help / links / ideas would be very appreciated and if I left some important things out, just comment and I will do my best to clarify them.

Comment: what are you using WFFM or Sitecore Form?

Comment: @AbhishekMalaviya I am using WFFM.

Answer (score 0):

As for me it is much more easier to pass data between forms using Session:

1. You add save action that write required data to Session
2. You add code to the thank you page that read value from Session